# Firebase Back-end code arrangement in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-access-layer, coding-style

I am working on a college project, my team and I are developing an application that includes users and groups, we are using Firebase for signing-up using Facebook, and almost every activity needs to get data from the Firebase real-time database. I am wondering if there is a coding convention for writing the code of manipulating the database.
For example, a lot of code samples look like this :

```
createGroupBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        group.addUser(firebaseuser.getUid());
            //add group to firebase
            String groupId=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Groups").addGroup(group);

            //set user's group id for this id
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(firebaseuser.getUid()).child("groupId").setValue(groupId);
```

I think it's so messy and not the right way of accessing the Database (inside of an activity.java class file). I can't think about a good way of arranging the code and creating data access layer that will make the code better and make my developing process go easier.
Any suggestions will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the Firebase calls into a service layer and expose the service methods.

Answer (score 1):

When I develop an android application, I always try to follow the **MVP (Model View Presenter)** pattern. 
So, you have to split all these 3 inside different package.

For Firebase, I use a folder with all my firebase function. These Firebase function call a CallBack which is link to a Presenter.

I don't know if it's the best way, but it's mine and it's respect the MVP pattern